# Is it possible to pull transaction records from an existing account in Yodlee MoneyCenter?

Tags: yodlee

Is it possible to pull transaction records from an existing account in Yodlee MoneyCenter?
I am trying to figure out if there is a public API for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee Moneycenter(now Yodlee Labs) is a platform which provides you much more than account aggregation features to use for free.
In case if you are looking for APIs to build something similar you can get access to the Yodlee APIs, which has been exposed to the developer community(though you have to pay for it).

Please visit developer.yodlee.com for more information about this.